# No relationship of type when opening Word document with Python

Tags: python, ms-word, python-docx

When trying to open a `.dot` file with `python-docx`, I am getting the error:

```
KeyError: "no relationship of type 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument' in collection"
```

This is the code in question:

```
from docx import Document
document = Document('file.dot')
```

What is the actual problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How did you generate the input file? [Here](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/204) it is an issue about the type when you save the file as *Strict Open XML Document*. Try the standard *Word document*.

You can get more informations about relations inside the file using [opc-diag](https://github.com/python-openxml/opc-diag):

```
opc browse <FILE> .rels
```

An idea to try to fix the bad file:

```
# Extract the bad file to a temporary folder
unzip <FILE> -d bad-file

# Repackage the extracted data to a new fresh file
opc repackage bad-file new-file.docx

# A diff of relationships
opc diff-item test.docx test-ok.docx .rels
```

Comment: I added opc-diag link in the answer. It is a small utility to explore and diagnose problems with Microsoft Office Open XML files.

Comment: Could you give us a link to the bad file?

Comment: I added an idea for a fix, could you test it?

Comment: I still keep getting the same error, even after repackaging. The file in question can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/i9x7byy2js0z5qy/aa.dot?dl=0

Comment: The only way I get rid of the error is by saving the current file to a DOCX file.

Comment: Be it as it may, I use the `docx` - not sure why the error occured though. Thanks for your continued help!

Comment: @Tiger-222: The .dot file was a legacy Word 97-2003 template format. Perhaps because it was saved from a recent version, it had a zip archive header and a few XML members (including [Content_Types].xml, apparently to allow some sort of partial handling by an OpenXML client. However, most of the file is that legacy binary content. The Word 97-2003 formats are not supported by `python-docx`. Saving it as .docx created it in that format.